# horizontal menu with 4 equally spaced elements

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I want to create a horizontal menu with 4 equally spaced elements. The menu has to be always sticked the browsers bottom.

The tricky part is, that the first elements string has to start at the left margin, and the last elements string hast to end at the right margin.

The strings between them should be equally spaced. The width of the menu should be scalable.
This is so far my closest solution, its not accurate tho :/

/*UPDATE*/ Collection should start at the edge of the browsers screen and Contact should end at the right edge of the browsers screen. (So with margins i meant the browsers very edge...)

DEMO:https://jsfiddle.net/t8kn1nch/

Do you have an idea?

HTML:

```
            <div id="navigation">
                <div id="collection">collection</div>
                <div id="shopabout">
                    <div id="shop">shop</div>
                    <div id="about">about</div>
                </div>
                <div id="contact">contact</div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#navigation div{
display: inline-block;
}

#navigation #collection{
float: left;
}

#navigation #shopabout{
width: 100%;
display: inline;

}
#navigation #shop{
width: calc(100%/1.8);
text-align: center;
}
#navigation #about{
display: inline;
}
#navigation #contact{
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK try this CSS.

```
#navigation{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#collection {
    width:25%;
}

#contact {
    width:25%;
}

#shopabout {
    width:50%;
}

#shop,
#about {
    width:50%;
}

#navigation div{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

#navigation #contact {
    text-align:right;
}

#navigation #collection {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: It looks almost how i imagined, but the tricky part is missing! The Strings didn't start at the edge of the screen. Sorry maybe "begin at margin" wasn't accurate described :/ , i meant that it really start at the edge of browsers screen.

Answer (score 0):

See jsfiddle with working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/45n3d6hs/2/

Css:

```
#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigation #collection, #navigation #contact {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}
#navigation #shop, #navigation #about {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#navigation #shopabout {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi dcardoso! Thank you for your code. The missing part is the same as in the other solutions of Aramil Rey and HelloWorld . Collection should start at the edge of the browsers screen and Contact should end at the right edge of the browsers screen.

Comment: You could set #navigation to use more than 100% of width of parent and use it like this: `width: 120%; margin-left: -10%`... margin-left should be half of the width you increased. Not a perfect solution, but otherwise I would use jscript as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [**THIS**](https://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/t8kn1nch/3/)?

```css
* {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
}
#navigation > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
#navigation > div:first-child, #navigation > div:last-child {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="collection">
    collection</div><div id="shop">
    shop</div><div id="about">
    about</div><div id="contact">
    contact</div>
</div>
```

The trick here is with HTML, using `display: inline-block` makes the space between divs to be readed just like an element, a spacebar.
Any white space between divs would ruin this layout, since you're taking 25% of the width with every div!

Comment: Its almost what i meant! The missing part is the same as in HelloWorld´s code, that the string, so "Collection" should start at the edge of the browers screen. Sorry i didn't described it properly in my question! Im going to update it. oh and thanks for helping  :)

Comment: the div "collection" is starting at the very beggining of the body, and the div of contact ends at the very end! The text is just center-aligned!

Comment: I changed the coulours for the first and last divs so its clearer that the width of the #navigation div is 100%, and each child div takes 25% of the screen - Run this full screen to clarify even further.

Answer (score 0):

Altough you can use some workarounds, proper solution here is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#collection, #contact {
    width: 25%;
}
#contact {
    text-align: right;
}
#shopabout {
    width: 50%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
}
#shop, #about {
    width: 50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8kn1nch/5/), let me know if it's a solution you needed.

Comment: Thanks, but the elements should be in the same line next to each other (equally spaced). Collection should start at the edge of the browsers screen and Contact should end at the right edge of the browsers screen.

Comment: I included this requirement in my solution. Or do I understand you wrong? Can you, I don't know, add a image of what you want to accomplish, because I'm really confused?